# Error issuing "make" command during ISIC package installation

Tags: linux, kali-linux

I am trying to install ISIC package in Kali Linux Rolling.
Followed the Install instructions from [here](https://github.com/dropletzhu/isic-fix/blob/master/INSTALL)

As a first step I've installed the libnet package and it went fine. Next when am trying to install ISIC package from the ISIC make file, it fails with following error message on console.

```
> gcc -o tcpsic tcpsic.c -Wall -W -g -O2 -I/usr/local/include
> `libnet-config --cflags` -DHAVE_LIBNET=1 -Din_addr_t=u_int32_t 
> `libnet-config --defines` -DVERSION=\"0.07\" -lnet -L/usr/local/lib 
> `libnet-config --libs` In file included from
> /usr/include/strings.h:26:0,
>                  from isic.h:1,
>                  from tcpsic.c:1: /usr/include/features.h:148:3: warning: #warning "_BSD_SOURCE and _SVID_SOURCE are deprecated, use
> _DEFAULT_SOURCE" [-Wcpp]  # warning "_BSD_SOURCE and _SVID_SOURCE are deprecated, use _DEFAULT_SOURCE"    ^~~~~~~ tcpsic.c: In function
> ‘main’: tcpsic.c:274:7: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete
> type ‘struct tcphdr’
>     tcp->th_off = rand() & 0xf;
>        ^~ Makefile:27: recipe for target 'tcpsic' failed make: *** [tcpsic] Error 1
```

---

Please help me fix this. I need this tool up and running for my test scenarios.

**Just In Case:** Is there any alternative way to install this ISIC package in my Kali Machine?

Comment: Welcome. This is not a security question but a compilation question in Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`isic-0.07` : Year 2006. Hence the 2014 update "isic-fix" https://github.com/dropletzhu/isic-fix

`$ git clone https://github.com/dropletzhu/isic-fix.git`

`$ cd isic-fix/ && ./configure && make` : Compiles OK with e.g. gcc-4.9 (or gcc-5).

Comment: Thank you very much, Knud Larsen. It worked pretty well in one go.